# How to submit form on Enter using DIV

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to make my form submit when enter is pressed inside the div that is acting as input. Any help?

Here is my code.

```js
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000");

const Chat = () => {
  
  let divText = "";
  
  const SendMessage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(divText);
    divText = "";
  }

  const HandleChange = (event) => {
    
    divText = event.target.textContent;
  }

  return (
    <div className='chat-div'>
        <div className='chat-box'>
          <span className='razmak'></span>
        </div>
        <form className='input-form' onSubmit={SendMessage} spellCheck='false'>
            <div className='chat-input' contentEditable='true' onInput={HandleChange}></div>
            <button className='send-button' type='submit'><AiOutlineSend/></button>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Chat;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd do is update your div to use an `onKeyDown` like this:

```js
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000");

const Chat = () => {
  let divText = "";

  const sendMessage = (event) => {
    alert("submit");
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(divText);
    divText = "";
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    divText = e.target.textContent;
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      sendMessage(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="chat-div">
      <div className="chat-box">
        <span className="razmak"></span>
      </div>
      <form className="input-form" onSubmit={sendMessage} spellCheck="false">
        <div
          className="chat-input"
          contentEditable="true"
          onKeyDown={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        ></div>
        <button className="send-button" type="submit">
          jhgj
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

There's a couple of other things, some which I've not included above:

- Lowercase the method names if they don't return JSX
- The `divText` should ideally use the `useState` React hook
- Consider using a standard input rather than a div, as this is semantically more correct, and accessible for people using screen readers.

Comment: I would use input. But I cant make input expand when more text is entered.